# Does Entity Framewok Code-First supports following yet?

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, ef-code-first

**Migrations for Oracle.** There are examples of creating Databases for MSSQL(and they work), but search for Oracle examples returns messages about errors. So can I use EF Migrations with Oracle databases yet?

**Production deployment.** Is there a way to create database Code-First way in runtime(okay, maybe this question is stupid), meaning: without running 'Update-Database' in Package Manager Console.
I read that EF team planned to support running this from Command-line or something, but what's status of this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to first question is no (I'm even not sure if provider model for other databases is already available). The answer to second question is yes - it is how common database initializer works but you cannot update the database at runtime. That requires migrations and migrations currently doesn't support this.